# How do I add ann array with a shape of (4,3) to my pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have this df

```
    col 1   col 2   col 3   col 3
0   323.0   1.0     179.0   420.0
1   131.0   88.0    1.0     917.0
2   872.0   1.0     1.0     811.0
3   1.0     352.0   230.0   769.0
```

and I would like to add my np array to the df with 3 columns

```
   out_values = [[ 1    1   1]
             [1 1   1]
             [212.2 209.7   212.1]
             [217.1 213.3   219.2]]
```

desired output

```
    col 1   col 2   col 3   col 3   0        1      2
0   323.0   1.0     179.0   420.0   1.0      1.0    1.0
1   131.0   88.0    1.0     917.0   1.0      1.0    1.0
2   872.0   1.0     1.0     811.0   212.2    209.7  212.1
3   1.0     352.0   230.0   769.0   217.1    213.3  219.2
```

My  current code is

```
ni_arr = ni_df.to_numpy()
out_values = [np.divide(ni_arr[0][1:], ni_arr[i][1:]) for i in range(ni_len)]
out_values = np.array( out_values )
```

But I am unsure how to then add my array to the df as shows in the desired output
I have tried to use `for i in range(len(ni_arr[0][1:])):` and combine this with something to get the column names (although I amn not sure this is the best way to go)  `ni_arr[0][1:]` returns the correct amount of columns in this case 3. But I have not been able to add the array to the df.

Note that the ni_df isnt the one used in the calculations of out_values but I dont think is relevent as its the output which I want to append. Although I mentioned just incase there was a better way of me doing the above steps which is to turn the df into an array and then divide the first row by each of the other rows which returns a list with column values for each row and then. I turn the list of values into a single array.

Comment: convert the array to a dataframe and use `pandas.merge` or `pandas.concat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with

```
 df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(out_values, index=df.index))
```

Answer (score 1):

**METHOD 1 :** `pd.concat`

You can use a pd.concat to achieve this -

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(out_values)], axis=1)
```

```
   col 1  col 2  col 3  col 4      0      1      2
0  323.0    1.0  179.0  420.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
1  131.0   88.0    1.0  917.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2  872.0    1.0    1.0  811.0  212.2  209.7  212.1
3    1.0  352.0  230.0  769.0  217.1  213.3  219.2
```

---

**METHOD 2:** `df.reindex`

```
#create new columns
df1 = df.reindex(columns=df.columns.to_list()+list(range(out_values.shape[1])))
#assign values to them
df1[list(range(out_values.shape[1]))] = out_values
```

```
   col 1  col 2  col 3  col 4      0      1      2
0  323.0    1.0  179.0  420.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
1  131.0   88.0    1.0  917.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2  872.0    1.0    1.0  811.0  212.2  209.7  212.1
3    1.0  352.0  230.0  769.0  217.1  213.3  219.2
```

---

**METHOD 3:** `df.join` (As answered by BEN_YO)

```
df1 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(out_values))
```

```
   col 1  col 2  col 3  col 4      0      1      2
0  323.0    1.0  179.0  420.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
1  131.0   88.0    1.0  917.0    1.0    1.0    1.0
2  872.0    1.0    1.0  811.0  212.2  209.7  212.1
3    1.0  352.0  230.0  769.0  217.1  213.3  219.2
```